# TypeScript doesn't understand this function with this argument gives this type

Tags: typescript, types

I don't understand why TypeScript gives me this error. Please help me fix it.

```js
type Admin = {
  id: string
  email: string
  password: string
  age: number
  isMaster: boolean
  // ...
}

type Student = {
  id: string
  name: string
  email: string
  age: number
  isActive: boolean
  // ...
}

type PropertyTypes<T> = T[keyof T]

type PropertySelector<T extends {}> = {
  [K in keyof T]: (k: K) => T[K]
}

interface BookshelfEntity<T extends {}> {
  get: PropertyTypes<PropertySelector<T>>
  toJSON: () => T
}

type User = BookshelfEntity<Student> | BookshelfEntity<Admin>

const getStudentId = (user: User): string => user.get('id')
//                                                    ^^^ 
//       Type 'string | number | boolean' is not assignable to type 'string'.
//       Type 'number' is not assignable to type 'string'.(2322)
//       Argument of type 'string' is not assignable to parameter of type 'never'.(2345)
```

Comment: That's not the error that this exact code produces for me. I'm getting `Argument of type 'string' is not assignable to parameter of type 'never'.` in the [playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play) (the link with code is too long to paste in a comment).

Comment: @Thomas the code is taken from a real project. There is has different error message because I removed some of the properties for this example. I changed the example code and updated the comment with the error to fit the example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this to get some insight:

```
type Test = PropertyTypes<PropertySelector<Student>>
```

This resolves to:

```
type Test = ((k: "id") => string) | ((k: "name") => string) | ((k: "email") => string)
```

So this is a *union type* of functions that each accept a particular string constant, but it doesn't tell us *which* of those function types is actually contained in a variable of type `Test`. So, to be able to call it, you need to provide an argument that is correct for *all* those signatures, i.e. a string that is equal to `"id"` and to `"name"` and to `"email"`. This is obviously impossible, so the argument type is resolved to `never`.

You can solve this particular problem by declaring the interface like this:

```
interface BookshelfEntity<T extends {}> {
  get<K extends keyof T>(k: K): T[K],
  toJSON: () => T
}
```

Now `get` is a single function with a generic signature, and its return value depends on its argument as you'd want.

---

However, you'll find that this is not enough:

```
type User = BookshelfEntity<Student> | BookshelfEntity<Admin>

const getStudentId = (user: User): string => user.get('id')
```

The error is:

> This expression is not callable.
> Each member of the union type `(<K extends keyof Student>(k: K) => Student[K]) | (<K extends keyof Admin>(k: K) => Admin[K])` has signatures, but none of those signatures are compatible with each other.

I'm not sure why this is happening; it may be a limitation on when or how generics are resolved to concrete types.

A workaround is to declare `User` slightly differently:

```
type User = BookshelfEntity<Student | Admin>
```

Now `User.get` has signature `<K extends "id" | "email">(k: K) => (Admin | Student)[K]`, i.e. any field that `Student` and `Admin` have in common. And the return value is the union of the return values that can be produced for that argument, i.e. if `Admin` has `id: number` and `Student` has `id: string`, then `get('id')` will have type `number | string`.